# change the clock time in a date column

Tags: r

I have a large data set like this:

```
SUB  DATE   
 1   4/16/2010 6:25 
 2   4/2/2010 7:35    
 3   5/30/2010 7:41      
 4   6/18/2010 8:10      
 5   6/8/2010 8:26   
...
```

I want to change the clock time of DATE to 00:00 (AM). The expected output should look like this:

```
SUB  DATE   
 1   4/16/2010 00:00 
 2   4/2/2010 00:00    
 3   5/30/2010 00:00      
 4   6/18/2010 00:00      
 5   6/8/2010 00:00   
...
```

Does anyone have idea about realizing this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the output (in your question) of `dput(head(yourdata))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strftime(paste(strptime(data$DATE,  "%m/%d/%Y"), "00:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

### Edit

It seems like this solution also doesn't return "POSIXct" object. If you"ll look in the `?strptime` documentation, you'll see that they specifically mentioning it:

> format
>   A character string. The default for the format methods is "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" if any
>   component has a time component which **is not midnight**, and "%Y-%m-%d" otherwise.

It was discussed here previously and there is a temporary workaround mentioned here:
[as.POSIXct with datetimes including midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756771/as-posixct-with-datetimes-including-midnight)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy with the `lubridate` package:

```
require(lubridate)
largedata$DATE2 <- mdy_hm(largedata$DATE)
hour(largedata$DATE2) <- 0
minute(largedata$DATE2) <- 0
```

Comment: The second line gave error: Error in parse_date_time(dates, orders, tz = tz, locale = locale, quiet = quiet) : 'nzchar()' requires a character vector @tmpname12345

Comment: Probably need an `as.character` step to convert the default factor column to character.