# Convert posixct time format into 00:00:00

Tags: r

I want convert the following the column of the dataframe in to 00:00:00 (HH:MM:SS) 
and `class of the output should be the "POSIXct" format`.

This is not an exact duplicate of [as.POSIXct with datetimes including midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756771/as-posixct-with-datetimes-including-midnight) because these times do not include midnight.

Here Column of the dataframe.

```
> gg
[1] "2018-01-16 10:29:00 IST" "2018-01-16 10:29:00 IST"
[3] "2018-01-16 10:29:00 IST" "2018-01-16 10:29:00 IST"
[5] "2018-01-16 10:29:00 IST" "2018-01-16 10:29:00 IST"
```

I tired the following code,it's not solve the my problem

```
  paste(as.Date(gg, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"00:00:00")

[1] "2018-01-16 00:00:00" "2018-01-16 00:00:00" "2018-01-16 00:00:00"
[4] "2018-01-16 00:00:00" "2018-01-16 00:00:00" "2018-01-16 00:00:00"
```

And i need class of the output should be in `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

So i am applying the `as.POSIXct`

and here missing the `00:00:00`

```
as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(gg, format="%Y-%m-%d"),"00:00:00"))

[1] "2018-01-16 IST" "2018-01-16 IST" "2018-01-16 IST" "2018-01-16 IST"
[5] "2018-01-16 IST" "2018-01-16 IST"
```

Required format is

```
[1] "2018-01-16 00:00:00 IST" "2018-01-16 00:00:00 IST"
[3] "2018-01-16 00:00:00 IST" "2018-01-16 00:00:00 IST"
[5] "2018-01-16 00:00:00 IST" "2018-01-16 00:00:00 IST"
```

And class should be `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`

Dataset

```
> dput(gg)
structure(c(1516078740, 1516078740, 1516078740, 1516078740, 1516078740, 
1516078740), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

Thank you.

Comment: format(gg,'%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 IST')

Comment: This is a different question from the one it's marked as an exact duplicate of. This question is asking how to make a time that is NOT midnight appear as if it is midnight, i.e., to round it to the day. The other question is asking how to force a time that IS midnight to show the 00:00:00 H:M:S information.  That answer can be used as part of the solution for this question, but it's a different question, and doesn't have any rounding component.

Comment: When you understand why this is a duplicate your problem will be solved.

Comment: Agree to disagree. `round(gg, units = "days")`  remains a POSIX object, and has been converted from a date that isn't midnight to a date that is midnight. `format()` converts it to character. Just because the desired behavior in a post can be reproduced with the answer to another post, does not make the question an EXACT duplicate.

Comment: Both questions ask essentially "why doesn't `as.POSIXct("2018-01-16 00:00:00")` display a time?".

Comment: Yes, and they are not exact duplicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a round method for POSIX.ct

```
round(gg, units = "days")
```

To get it to display the 00:00:00

```
format(round(gg, units = "day"), '%Y-%m-%d %M:%H:%S')
```

Round has the benefit of being locale independent.