# Parsing dates with different formats

Tags: r, date, parsing

I have a csv file with a column containing dates, but the dates are in two different formats: "m/d/y H:M" and "y m d H:M:S". I want to make a new column with these dates all in one format (I don't care which one). I tried the parse_date_time function but it would only work for one of the formats, not both. How can I go about doing this?

Here is the code I was trying to use:

```
newdata <- mutate(data,
                        newcolumn = parse_date_time(x = data$date_column,
                                                        orders = c("m/d/y H:M", "y m d H:M:S"),
                                                        locale = "eng") )
```

Here are some example dates from the column:

```
x <- c("6/21/2006 0:00",
       "1889-06-13 00:00:00",
       "6/28/2012 0:00",
       "5/19/2015 0:00",
       "6/6/2016 0:00",
       "1884-05-24 00:00:00",
       "7/28/2013 0:00")
```

Comment: can you post the column? it will make it easier to answer and make sure the answer actually works for you

Comment: @DanHall I just added some sample dates from the column, it's a very large data set so I can't post it all

Comment: For future reference, use `dput(x)`,  where `x` is a small subset of your object that reproduces the problem and has all of the characteristics of your object. Copy and paste the output of `dput` as part of your question. But I think I've provided an answer for you below that should work.

Comment: OK, NOW it works. That was trickier than I thought it would be :)

Answer (score 3):

The `anytime` package does just that -- heuristically evaluating plausible formats:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> x <- c("6/21/2006 0:00",
+        "1889-06-13 00:00:00",
+        "6/28/2012 0:00",
+        "5/19/2015 0:00",
+        "6/6/2016 0:00",
+        "1884-05-24 00:00:00",
+        "7/28/2013 0:00")
R> anytime(x)
[1] "2006-06-21 CDT" "1889-06-13 CST" "2012-06-28 CDT"
[4] "2015-05-19 CDT" NA               "1884-05-24 CST"
[7] "2013-07-28 CDT"
R>
```

It uses Boost's date_time library parser by default, and that one does *not* do single digit month/day, hence the `NA` on element six.  But we also added R's parser as a fallback:

```
R> anytime(x, useR=TRUE)
[1] "2006-06-21 CDT" "1889-06-13 CST" "2012-06-28 CDT"
[4] "2015-05-19 CDT" "2016-06-06 CDT" "1884-05-24 CST"
[7] "2013-07-28 CDT"
R>
```

So here is *all just works* without a single format specification.

Answer (score 3):

Using `lubridate::parse_date_time()`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

x <- c("6/21/2006 0:00",
       "1889-06-13 00:00:00",
       "6/28/2012 0:00",
       "5/19/2015 0:00",
       "6/6/2016 0:00",
       "1884-05-24 00:00:00",
       "7/28/2013 0:00")

df <- data_frame(date_column = x)
df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_column = parse_date_time(date_column, orders = c('ymdHMS', "mdyHM")))

df_new
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  date_column         new_column         
  <chr>               <dttm>             
1 6/21/2006 0:00      2006-06-21 00:00:00
2 1889-06-13 00:00:00 1889-06-13 00:00:00
3 6/28/2012 0:00      2012-06-28 00:00:00
4 5/19/2015 0:00      2015-05-19 00:00:00
5 6/6/2016 0:00       2016-06-06 00:00:00
6 1884-05-24 00:00:00 1884-05-24 00:00:00
7 7/28/2013 0:00      2013-07-28 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

So we start by separating the two:

```
x <- c("03/20/2018 10:42", "2018-03-20 10:37:02")
DF <- data.frame(x = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
slash_index <- grep("/", DF$x)
slash <- DF$x[slash_index]
dash <- DF$x[-slash_index]
```

Then we convert them. I like lubridate, but you can use your method if you'd like

```
library(lubridate)
slash <- mdy_hm(slash)
dash <- ymd_hms(dash)
```

Then we put them into a date vector:

```
date_times <- integer(0)
date_times[slash_index] <- slash
date_times[seq_along(DF$x)[-slash_index]] <- dash
DF$x <- as.POSIXct(date_times, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00")
DF
#                     x
# 1 2018-03-20 03:42:02
# 2 2018-03-20 03:37:02
```

Note:
The tricky part here was re-assigning parts of a vector to a vector according to their index. When a portion of a vector was assigned to a `POSIXct` object, it had its attributes stripped, turning it into the internal integer code for the date time. This was resolved by stripping the attributes at the beginning, and then re-assigning the class at the end.

Here's the full thing with your example:

```
install.packages("lubridate")
library(lubridate)
x <- c("6/21/2006 0:00",
       "1889-06-13 00:00:00",
       "6/28/2012 0:00",
       "5/19/2015 0:00",
       "6/6/2016 0:00",
       "1884-05-24 00:00:00",
       "7/28/2013 0:00")
DF <- data.frame(x = x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
slash_index <- grep("/", DF$x)
slash <- DF$x[slash_index]
dash <- DF$x[-slash_index]


slash <- mdy_hm(slash)
dash <- ymd_hms(dash)


date_times <- integer(0)
date_times[slash_index] <- slash
date_times[seq_along(DF$x)[-slash_index]] <- dash
DF$x <- as.POSIXct(date_times, origin = "1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")
DF
#            x
# 1 2006-06-21
# 2 1889-06-13
# 3 2012-06-28
# 4 2015-05-19
# 5 2016-06-06
# 6 1884-05-24
# 7 2013-07-28
```

Because the times for these are all `"00:00:00"`, they've been truncated. You can display them with the `"00:00:00"` using the method described in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756771/as-posixct-with-datetimes-including-midnight).