# R convert "Y-m-d" or "m/d/Y" to the same format

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a **huge** (~10.000.000 rows) dataframe with a column that consists dates, i.e:

```
df <- data.frame(StartDate = as.character(c("2014-08-20 11:59:38", 
                                            "2014-08-21 16:17:44", 
                                            "2014-08-22 19:02:10",
                                            "9/1/2014 08:05:13",
                                            "9/2/2014 15:13:28", 
                                            "9/3/2014 00:22:01")))
```

The problem is that date formats are mixed - I would like to standardise them so as to get:

```
   StartDate
1 2014-08-20
2 2014-08-21
3 2014-08-22
4 2014-09-01
5 2014-09-02
6 2014-09-03
```

**1. as.Date()** approach

```
as.Date("2014-08-31 23:59:38", "%m/%d/%Y")
as.Date("9/1/2014 00:00:28", "%m/%d/%Y")
```

gives

```
[1] NA
[1] "2014-09-01"
```

**2. lubridate** approach

```
dmy("9/1/2014 00:00:28")
mdy("9/1/2014 00:00:28")
dmy("2014-08-31 23:59:38")
mdy("2014-08-31 23:59:38")
```

in each case returns

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Is there any neat solution to that?

Comment: Does this have you covered? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49390707/5325862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier maybe to use `parse_date`

```
library(parsedate)
df$StartDate <- as.Date(parse_date(df$StartDate))
```

-output

```
> df$StartDate
[1] "2014-08-20" "2014-08-21" "2014-08-22" "2014-09-01" "2014-09-02" "2014-09-03"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out that `anytime::anydate` extracts the dates directly and straightforwardly:

```r
library(anytime)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = anydate(StartDate))

#>             StartDate       Date
#> 1 2014-08-20 11:59:38 2014-08-20
#> 2 2014-08-21 16:17:44 2014-08-21
#> 3 2014-08-22 19:02:10 2014-08-22
#> 4   9/1/2014 08:05:13 2014-09-01
#> 5   9/2/2014 15:13:28 2014-09-02
#> 6   9/3/2014 00:22:01 2014-09-03
```

---

Another solution, based on `lubridate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = if_else(!str_detect(StartDate,"/"), 
    date(ymd_hms(StartDate, quiet = T)), date(mdy_hms(StartDate, quiet = T))))

#>             StartDate       Date
#> 1 2014-08-20 11:59:38 2014-08-20
#> 2 2014-08-21 16:17:44 2014-08-21
#> 3 2014-08-22 19:02:10 2014-08-22
#> 4   9/1/2014 08:05:13 2014-09-01
#> 5   9/2/2014 15:13:28 2014-09-02
#> 6   9/3/2014 00:22:01 2014-09-03
```