# R lubridate package date-time creation omits time at midnight

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I am trying to create date-time using lubridate package, and I've tried the following values:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms("2017-07-02 23:00:00")
[1] "2017-07-02 23:00:00 UTC"
ymd_hms("2017-07-02 00:00:00")
[1] "2017-07-02 UTC"
```

It seems that if you type the time at midnight, 00:00:00, the ymd_hms() method ignores the time value, and the result becomes a date. Is there any way to show the 00:00:00 in the result?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a bug in the package. Remarkably the midnight time is displayed if the dates are concatenated: `ymd_hms(c("2017-07-02 23:00:00", "2017-07-02 00:00:00"))`.

Comment: That's quite interesting! I am still exploring it.

Comment: Also, I tried to create a date-time at 23:59:59, and add 1 second, it still doesn't show 00:00:00. `test <- ymd_hms("20180303 23:59:59")
test "2018-03-03 23:59:59 UTC" test + seconds(1) "2018-03-04 UTC" `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I just got my own answer to this question after google searches and error trying:

```
mydates <- format(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
mydates
[1] "01-01-2011 00:00:00"
format(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC"), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "01-01-2011 00:00:00"
```

It seems that using the R Base as.POSIXct with format arguments works.

Answer (score 2):

The print is different, but the object is still a `POSIXct` :

```r
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(magrittr)

ymd_hms("2017-07-02 23:00:00")%>% 
  class()
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

ymd_hms("2017-07-02 00:00:00") %>% 
  class()
#> [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Created on 2018-07-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  fr_FR.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       Europe/Paris                
#>  date     2018-07-05
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package   * version date       source                          
#>  backports   1.1.2   2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  base      * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  compiler    3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  datasets  * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  devtools    1.13.6  2018-06-27 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                  
#>  digest      0.6.15  2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  evaluate    0.10.1  2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                  
#>  graphics  * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  grDevices * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  htmltools   0.3.6   2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                  
#>  knitr       1.20    2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  lubridate * 1.7.4   2018-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                  
#>  magrittr  * 1.5     2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                  
#>  memoise     1.1.0   2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.0)                  
#>  methods   * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  Rcpp        0.12.17 2018-05-18 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                  
#>  rmarkdown   1.10    2018-06-11 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                  
#>  rprojroot   1.3-2   2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                  
#>  stats     * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  stringi     1.2.3   2018-06-12 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                  
#>  stringr     1.3.1   2018-05-10 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                  
#>  tools       3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  utils     * 3.4.4   2018-03-15 local                           
#>  withr       2.1.2   2018-06-01 Github (jimhester/withr@70d6321)
#>  yaml        2.1.19  2018-05-01 CRAN (R 3.4.4)
```

Comment: Thanks Colin, I must re-phrase my word, it looks like a date, but still I know it is a date-time object. It's just it doesn't show the 00:00:00, but I got a way to format the result so that it shows 00:00:00.