# Converting valid midnight calendartime to POSIXct and then to text and back to POSIXct results in NA?

Tags: r, datetime, na, posixct

Let's say you got a datetime in a text class at exactly midnight, say for instance: "2023-11-16 00:00:00" and you create a POSIXct object with that datetime using as.POSIXct. Then, you use as.character() to convert it to text, so as.character() wipes the last part corresponding to "00:00:00" resulting in "2023-11-16". Now you use POSIXct with the "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" format date and, surprisingly it transforms the output to NA, which is not the initial value.

Let me show you it with code to be more clear:

```
> datetime = "2022-03-12 00:00:00"
> posix = as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Europe/Madrid")
> posix
[1] "2022-03-12 CET"
> as.POSIXct(as.character(posix), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Europe/Madrid")
[1] NA
```

Or, in one line:

```
> as.POSIXct(as.character(as.POSIXct(datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Europe/Madrid")), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="Europe/Madrid")
[1] NA
```

I would expect that transforming back the text version of the datetime to POSIXct would result in the initial value. But, instead, it results in NA, which breaks my following code.

I temporally fixed it by using strftime() function to convert from POSIXct to text, but I would expect another function like as.character() which is time-zone agnostic.

Somehow related to [as.POSIXct with datetimes including midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756771/as-posixct-with-datetimes-including-midnight).

Comment: The format specification of your outer `as.POSIXct()`-call does not match the format of the output of `as.character()`, i.e. `"2022-03-12 CET"`. I think you need to pad the previously deleted time information back in. As it's lost, remove `"%H:%M:%S"` from the outer `as.POSIXct()`-call. That is the closed `as.POSIXct()` can guess based on the information given I think. What is the gain of `as.character()`?

Comment: Well, I don't have a good argument to do the as.character() part to transform it back to POSIXct, but the issue comes from two reasons:
 1) I'm using an external library which takes whatever input, do as.character() and then do the as.POSIXct() and my input is in POSIXct which makes the external function to fail, giving the input with as.character also fails because of what I described above so I would have to pad the missed 00:00:00 for thousands of rows that I have at midnight.

Comment: 2) I would expect that as.character is not an "irreversible destructive function", so I could do any times of as.character(  as.POSIXct() ) combinations. Likewise I can do with factor variables or with POSIXct and any other datetime that is not 00:00:00